# MySQL - How to get a list of user-defined variables and their Values?

Tags: mysql, variables, session

Does anyone know if we can get a list of user-defined variables for the current session in the latest version of MySQL?

For example, if I do this:

```
SET @var1 = JSON_OBJECT('test1','test2');
SET @var2 = 'Hello World!';
```

I'd like to get a list of these somehow, but SHOW SESSION VARIABLES does not show these user-defined variables.

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely any allowed variable name matches the variable which already exists - simply its value is NULL.

Comment: But you may look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-user-variable-tables.html

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @akina for pointing me in the right direction!

Here's how you get the list of all Custom Session Variables by each thread currently active on the server for a specific database:

```
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.user_variables_by_thread;
```